# How to move svn folder one level up

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I need to move svn folder to one level up and keep all history

All files and directories from `https://myserver.com/svn/Project/trunk/`
into `https://myserver/svn/Project/`

I use a command:

```
svn move https://myserver.com/svn/Project/trunk/ https://myserver/svn/Project/
```

but it says:

> svn: Cannot move path 'https://myserver.com/svn/Project/trunk/'
>    into itself

Who knows how can I resolve that problem?
Thanks!

Comment: The repository layout looks sensible. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496713/how-do-i-correct-a-subversion-project-where-i-omitted-trunk

Comment: Thanks, because trunk in my situation is just one extra chain, it's unnecessary to have it.

Comment: As to link you send me, there guy needs add that additional directory "trunk" to the chain, i need remove it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are willing to use TortoiseSVN then you can simply move the folder with the repository browser. That is how I usually move folders around, very simple and painless.

Comment: Yes, I use TortoiseSVN, it's really very simple in repository browser, Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: How do you commit that later? or is it "commited" by click? thx!

Comment: As far as I recall this creates a commit automatically.

Answer (score 21):

I was just looking for this as well. Then I started looking for a solution and I didn't really find one, except that it did make me think of a solution.

You'd expect the command `svn mv ./folder ./` to move everything from the `./folder` to `./`. This isn't actually true, it'll move `folder` into the current directory. Since this is where it already is, the command fails.

So, the solution would be to move everything ***inside*** `./folder` to `./`. Indeed, the following command does just that:

`svn mv ./folder/* ./`

Answer (score 1):

I don;t know if you can move it that way, personally I would checkout repository, move folder in filesystem and then commit changes, deleting it at one location and adding at another.

Comment: you will not keep the history, after that you will have only last revision

Comment: why? you'll have all changes, but in new tree.

Comment: as i thought of the problem a little bit i found another solution - dump repository at a specified tree, let's say:

svnadmin dump repo/path/other/inner > file.dump

then delete dir "inner" -> it will remove it from repository, and now load it at another path:

svnadmin load /repo/ --parent-dir /path < file.dump

that way you'll have all directory tree committed and history saved

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> svn switch --relocate https://myserver.com/svn/Project/trunk/ https://myserver/svn/Project/

Please test this in a seperate repository before you run it on your real one!

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but svn says: svn: '.' is not a working copy

Comment: You ran the command from the base directory of the project on your file system?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue today but I didn't know how to move it up from tortoise, since I also had settings for that folder.

If the new location `https://myserver/svn/Project/` should have only the items from your old location, here is what I did:

- Moved `https://myserver.com/svn/Project/trunk/` to a new temporary location (e.g. `https://myserver/svn/TempProject/`);
- Deleted the existing location you want to use (`https://myserver/svn/Project/`);
- Renamed `https://myserver/svn/TempProject/` to `https://myserver/svn/Project/`.

This worked for me. It preserved all history, svn settings, etc. The history just got a couple new entries from all the moving around thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can move directly to existing directory (especially repository root). Maybe `--force` option could help.

If it's possible to checkout whole repo you could move every directory from trunk to upper level, it seems like more reliable solution

```
svn mv * ..
```

`*` is not supported by some svn clients

Answer (score -1):

1. check out https://myserver.com/svn to some working copy
2. delete directory "Project"
3. copy last revision of Project/trunk to the root of the working copy
4. commit